# Маска ввода из значений массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, inputmask

Как можно реализовать маску ввода, критерием совпадения которой был бы инкрементируемый ряд либо значения из массива, например 100, 200, 300, 400... с использованием или без сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать нативным инпутом. При необходимости уже в js динамически контролировать значение атрибутов.

```html
<input type="number" step="100" min="100" max="500">
```

Comment: Ну так я же могу вручную ввести любое промежуточное значение

Comment: Можно запретить события клавиатуры
**input.addEventListener('keydown', evt => evt.preventDefault())**

Comment: Если max будет 1 000 000 и шаг будет 10, нужно будет до утра кнопку нажимать

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать функцию inArray, которая будет принимать два параметра: значение и массив, и проверять есть ли такое значение в массиве, и возвращать тру или фолс. Потом вызывать эту функцию с value инпута, и нужным массивом, и выводить сообщение о том что значение недопустимо, и очищать инпут или ничего не делать, если значение допустимо

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input')
const array = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

const inArray = (array, value) => array.includes(parseInt(value))

const mask = event => {
    if (!inArray(array, event.target.value)) {
        event.target.value = ''
        alert(`Допустимые значения для ввода: ${array}`)
    }
}

input.addEventListener('change', mask)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```